# Enzyme | Conditionally check for props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I want to test that the correct component is being rendered when a prop has specific values `true` or `false`.

Here is the code:

```
/* eslint-disable react/default-props-match-prop-types */
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';
import ILicense from 'dto/ILicense';

import Icon from 'components/Icon';

export interface Props {
  license?: ILicense;
}

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type
const LicenseInfo = <T extends object>({ license }: Props & T) => (
  <Fragment>
    {license ? (
      <Fragment>
        <div className="py-5 mx-3">
          {license.isValid? (
            <div>
              <Icon icon="check" className="fa-lg text-success mr-2" />
              License is Valid
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div>
              <Icon icon="exclamation-circle" className="fa-lg text-danger mr-2" />
              License has expired
            </div>
          )}
      </Fragment>
    ) : null}
  </Fragment>
);

LicenseInfo.defaultProps = {
  clientId: '',
  expiry: null,
  isValid: true,
};

export default LicenseInfo;
```

And here is my test case: `If the prop isValid is true`, the render the Icon component with icon prop `check` else the other one.

Here is my test:

```
  it('expect to show check Icon when license.isValid prop is true', () => {
    const wrapper = mount<LicenseInfo>(<LicenseInfo isValid="true">Test</LicenseInfo>);
    const check = wrapper.find(<Icon icon="check" />).props;
    console.log(check);
    expect(check).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

The problem I think is in the `check`. Ι `console.log` it and get this `ReactWrapper {}`..

Any ideas on how to correctly do this...? Thanks!!

Comment: You're missing a `</div>` tag in your component, but other than that it looks fine.  I get `[Function: props]` as expected from the `console.log` line

Comment: Yeah that's fine. The `div` I mean. I abstracted the remaining code in the component. Not sure what is wrong here... Will keep you updated if I figure it out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from Enzyme'e docs [`find()`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/find.html) expect [`EnzymeSelector`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/selector.html) to be passed. And this should be

1. CSS-like selector(`Icon[icon=check]` in your case)
2. constructor name(`Icon`)
3. display name(`'Icon'`)
4. object with properties

You are passing JSX element there so that finds nothing.

So I believe

```
it('expect to show check Icon when license.isValid prop is true', () => {
  const wrapper = mount<LicenseInfo>(<LicenseInfo isValid="true">Test</LicenseInfo>);
  const iconType = wrapper.find(Icon).prop('icon');
  expect(iconType).toEqual('check');
});
```

should work for you

Answer (score 0):

i have no idea why you doing this

```
const check = wrapper.find(<Icon icon="check" />).props;
```

if you need check prop

```
it('expect to show check Icon when license.isValid prop is true', () => {
  const wrapper = mount<LicenseInfo>(<LicenseInfo isValid="true">Test</LicenseInfo>);
  const check = wrapper.props().isValid;
  console.log(check);
  expect(check).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Comment: you are checking property you have passed. actually it would test only React works as expected. question's author wanted to check internals of their component and how does it depend on prop values passed